# Positve or negative?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> All person shall be a Senator or Representative in Congress, or elector of President and Vice President, or hold any office, civil or military, under the United States, or under any state, who, having previously taken an oath, as a member of Congress, or as an officer of the United States, or as a member of any state legislature, or as an executive or judicial officer of any state, to support the Constitution of the United States, **shall have engaged in insurrection or rebellion against the same, or given aid or comfort to the enemies thereof**. But Congress may by a vote of two-thirds of each House, remove such disability.

I think that the bold part should expresses a negative meaning. When I put it into a language translator, it shows so too. But there isn't a "not" in it. Does I understand it wrongly?

I also don't understand what the word "disability" has to do with previous words.

Comment: Where's this quote from? Certainly not the US Constitution — that's simply not what it says. Section 3 of article 14 starts out with "**No** person shall be…"

Comment: @Laurel https://flexbooks.ck12.org/user:zxbpc2rzcziwmthaz21hawwuy29t/cbook/episd-united-states-government-2019-2020/section/2.6/primary/lesson/limited-government-and-the-rule-of-law/   see section 3.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a badly copied text.

Comment: Looks like a bad translation to me. The sentence reads "all person shall be a senator who shall have engaged in insurrection ". Doesn't sound right for some reason..

Comment: It's a direct quote from the US Constitution, the 14th Amendment. Yes, the first word is wrong. It should be "No person ..." not "All person ...". Besides that, and maybe one would make something of the fact that in the original "state" is capitalized i.e. "State legislature", besides that the quote is accurate.

Comment: _Disabil.ity_, sense 3: " Incapacity in the eye of the law, or created by the law; a restriction framed to prevent any person or class of persons from sharing in duties or privileges which would otherwise be open to them; legal disqualification." (OED). This meaning is not now common except in legal contexts.

Answer (score 1):

No, the statement is supposed to be positive. It's a complicated sentence, and in such cases it's often helpful to strip out all the qualifiers to get down to the core sentence.

In this case, "No person shall be a Senator (etc) ... who ... shall have engaged in insurrection." That is, if someone engaged in insurrection, he can't hold one of the listed offices. So it's a positive assertion: If you engaged in insurrection, then you can't hold this office. The first part of the sentence is negative, "no person shall ...", if you meet the condition, then you can't do this.

This amendment was passed after the Civil War, and the point was to say that politicians who had participated in the South seceding from the Union could not be members of Congress.

I'm not sure what your problem is with "disability". Perhaps you are looking at a definition that says "disability" means a physical handicap, like being paralyzed or blind. This is the most common use of the word. But it can also mean any lack of ability. Like we sometimes say things like, "Bob disabled the backup system" to mean he stopped the backup system from working. In this case, the "disability" is the restriction that such people cannot hold the named offices. Congress can vote to allow a person to hold office despite him having participated in insurrection. And in fact Congress passed the "Amnesty Act" in 1872 restoring the right to hold office to most people affected by this amendment.

Comment: Thanks for you help. It's clear now.